# Comparison of byte instances and byte array instances

Tags: c#, .net

Why: new byte() == new byte() returns true, but new byte[0] == new byte[0] returns false?

Here is the code example:

```
var result1 = new byte() == new byte(); // true
var result2 = new byte[0] == new byte[0]; // false
```

Why does it happen that result1 is true and result2 is false?

Comment: Because `byte` is a value type and `Array` is a reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compare two *arrays*, it compares the reference (i.e. the address/identity of that specific array object), *not* the contents. Since you've created two different arrays, they have different references, and thus it returns `false`.

Comparing *bytes*, however, is done by comparing the value, and zero equals zero.

In theory the runtime *could* return the same memoized empty array for every `new Foo[0]` call, but that would be a breaking change for the reason you're seeing: it would change an observable behaviour. Perhaps contradictory, but `new string(...)` with a zero-length *does* now often do exactly this, returning the interned `""`.